# chkconfig wont install tomcat8

Tags: tomcat, startup, chkconfig, runlevel

I have tomcat8 intalled on my Amazon Linux AMI, I modified the tomcat8 init script header, so chkconfig could install tomcat8 to run automatically on boot. The modified header is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# tomcat      This shell script takes care of starting and stopping Tomcat
#
# chkconfig: 345 80 20
# description: Release implementation for Servlet 3.0 and JSP 2.2

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: tomcat
# Required-Start: $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $network $syslog
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Description: Release implementation for Servlet 3.0 and JSP 2.2
# Short-Description: start and stop tomcat
### END INIT INFO
#
# - originally written by Henri Gomez, Keith Irwin, and Nicolas Mailhot
# - heavily rewritten by Deepak Bhole and Jason Corley
#
```

I as you can see I set it to run on runlevels 3, 4, and 5.

Then I runned:

```
sudo chkconfig --add tomcat8
```

And to my dispair after running the `--list` option, tomcat8 is `off` for all runlevels:

```
$ sudo chkconfig --add tomcat8
$ chkconfig --list tomcat8
tomcat8         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

**What's going on? What am I missing? Why isn't chkconfig turning tomcat8 `on` on levels 3, 4 and 5?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--add` switch only adds a **new service** for management by [`chkconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig). If the service is already present and has a symlink in every  `/etc/rc[0-6].d` directory that won't do anything...

To **modify** the runlevels in which tomcat8 should be started you didn't need to edit the init script, but simply run:

```
chkconfig --level 345 tomcat8 on
```

or alternatively after you modified the init file either use the `reset` switch:

```
chkconfig --level 0123456 reset
```

or first delete the existing symlinks from `/etc/rc[0-6].d` and then add them again:

```
chkconfig --del tomcat8
chkconfig --add tomcat8
```